# Sending selected image from gallery to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-gallery

This is the first time I am working with images.

I have created an activity in which I would be picking an image from the gallery and I want that image to be passed to next activity when a button is clicked.

Comment: Just need to pass the file url to the next activity via Intent extras but please, try it and post your code before.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be passing its Uri through the Intent.

First Activity:

```
Uri imageUri = /* This is the Uri you got from the gallery */
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("image-uri", imageUri.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Second Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("image-uri"));
/* Do something with imageUri */
```

Answer (score 0):

On possible approach would be:

1 - Store the image or image url after you get it on `onActivityResult()`

2 - Inside your button's `OnClickListener()` put an extra (in case you already have the bitmap) in your intent.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("image", yourImage);
            CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

3 - Get the extra on the new Activity (inside onCreate()).

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent.getExtras() != null){
        loadedImage = intent.getParcelableExtra("image");
    }
```

Comment: image should be selected from the gallery. Its not placed in the Drawable.

Comment: Yes I understood that. But when you go over the gallery and select an image, you process the resultant data in `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);}`. I assume that you already have this done. Whenever you reach this, you collect the resultant url (selected image url) and then you can get the image. After this you follow what I said in the answer and it will work

Answer (score -1):

First create bitmap from your imageview image

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Second, pass the bitmap to another activity via intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and last, in your new activity get bitmap from intent and set it into imageview

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
imageView.setBitmap(bitmap);
```